# Using two values from a function

Tags: swift, function

I've started to make a basic quiz game using Swift. I've written a struct to define what I want relating to each question:

```
struct Question {
  let question: String
  let answers: [String]
  let correctAnswer: Int
}
```

The game will be a basic maths quiz, so will show random maths questions. I've written a function to randomise the questions and obtain the answers:

```
func questionAnswerBuilder() -> (question: String, answer: String) {
let first: Int = randomNumber()
let second: Int = randomNumber()
let arr = [first,second].sorted(by: >)

let firstAsString = String(arr[0])
let secondAsString = String(arr[1])

let questionString = "\(firstAsString) + \(secondAsString)"
let question = questionString

//Answer:
let answerString = first + second
let answer = String(answerString)

return (question, answer)
}
```

I have tested this in playgrounds and it works fine. Each time it creates a random number and outputs that along with the correct answer. Now I'd like to use this in each question...

```
var questionTest = questionAnswerBuilder()

var questions: [Question] = [
Question(question: questionTest.question, answers: [randomAnswer(), randomAnswer(), questionAnswerBuilder().answer, randomAnswer()], correctAnswer: 2),
Question(question: questionTest.question, answers: [randomAnswer(), randomAnswer(), questionAnswerBuilder().answer, randomAnswer()], correctAnswer: 2)
]
```

For info, the `randomAnswer()` function is not displayed here. It's basically just a random number generator.

When I input all of this into Xcode I get the following message:
`Cannot use instance member 'questionTest' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`.

I currently have the `questionAnswerBuilder()` function in its own swift file. I have tried moving this to the same file as my `questions` variable but I still get the same fault. I have also tried making the `questionTest` variable lazy but this makes no difference.

Please please please could someone point out where I am going wrong!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot initialize properties which depend on each other on the top level of a class.

A solution is to initialize `questions` lazily

```
lazy var questions: [Question] = {
    return [Question(question: questionTest.question, answers: [randomAnswer(), randomAnswer(), questionAnswerBuilder().answer, randomAnswer()], correctAnswer: 2),
            Question(question: questionTest.question, answers: [randomAnswer(), randomAnswer(), questionAnswerBuilder().answer, randomAnswer()], correctAnswer: 2)]
}()
```

Comment: Excellent it worked! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you can’t use instance variables inside other instance variables.

You could fix this by changing your `questions` array to `lazy var questions`.

This will not create the array at the point of instantiating it. It will only create the array the first time you access it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already seen the post you have marked as a duplicate - it makes more sense now! Thanks